# git svn clone result cannot be cloned

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I've got several Subversion repositories for which I'm the only committer. Based on Paul Dowman's excellent [instructions](http://pauldowman.com/2008/07/26/how-to-convert-from-subversion-to-git/), I did the following:

```
$ git svn clone https://localhost/svn/settings --no-metadata -Aauthors.txt
Initialized empty Git repository in .git/
...
r1000 = 8655353158ef2e7be84c0115b16a14d327e9e842 (git-svn)
Running git repack -d ...
Counting objects: 5598, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (4646/4646), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5598/5598), done.
Total 5598 (delta 3023), reused 0 (delta 0)
Done repacking
```

I know there are more than 1000 revisions in the repo; how do I clone all of them?

Edit: Tried adding `-r 1:HEAD`, but it didn't make any difference.

Edit 2: Tried adding `--repack=0`, still doesn't work.

Comment: you want see the logs? I don't get what you mean by clone all of them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, I was able to get at least the recent history by using `-r 1000:HEAD` (I have 1879 revisions).